# Spring 3.2 and @WebFilter annontation..is it supported?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I can't seem to find anything that talks about using the @WebFilter annotation, and having Spring 3.2 AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer correctly handle the params used.

Does Spring 3.2 support that annotation?

EDIT: based upon nicohlas answer

If I use the @WebFilter annontation, and set params inside of that...it looks like AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer registerServletFilter does not look at those annontations and setup things properly from those params:  e.g url-mappings

Knowing that Spring 3.2 supports Servlet 3.0, shouldn't it support @WebFilter?

or am i missing the whole point of the WebFilter annontation?

EDIT 2:

When I deploy my war, and have @WebFilters defined inside that war, the container looks to "register" those...but, for some reason, even with the proper urlPatterns set, when the request comes into the DispatchServlet...it's like the filter doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

[`@WebFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html) is a JEE6 component, and is new to Servlet 3.0.

It is not something that Spring would support, but rather your application container (Tomcat, WebSphere, Glassfish, JBoss,...)

The idea here is to move configuration of your application container to Java, rather than utilizing the `web.xml` deployment descriptor.

***EDIT:***

It would seem to me that using the `@WebFilter` annotation would be for discovering `Filter`'s via classpath scanning.  The [`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer#registerServletFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html#registerServletFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletContext,%20javax.servlet.Filter%29) method that you are asking about is taking in a `Filter` and does not look at the annotations on it.

Comment: Understood about all of the above...thanks.  Perhaps i need rephrase the question better.

Comment: Yeah, looked at the src on github...the registerServletFilter doesn't care about the annotations.  I think i also see what you are saying..that @WebFilter regsiters with the ServletContext..so all servlets can use the filters.    

I wonder how i can get the Dispatch Servlet to use them..because it appears they do not get called when for somereason..I see them "register" but, they are not called with the DispatchServlet gets called...really werid

Comment: I would imagine you could utilize (ie, override) the `getServletFilters()` method of the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` to specify the `Filter`'s for your `DispatcherServlet`.  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html#getServletFilters()

Comment: trying now, but, it looks like Spring uses SerlvetNames, and not urlPatterns to match filters